# How to plot the weekend days in a scatterplot as different?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, plotly, scatter-plot

I have the following data table (only an example) `dt.data`:

```
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                      DE = rnorm(365, 4, 1), AT = rnorm(365, 10, 2), 
                      IT = rnorm(365, 1, 2), check.names = FALSE)

# Add nr-column for different colored points: #
dt.data$nr <- sort(rep(1:7, length.out = nrow(dt.data)))

## PLOT: ##
p <- ggplot(data = dt.data, aes(x = AT, y = DE, color = as.factor(nr),
                                text = paste("Date: ", date, '\n',
                                            "AT: ", AT, "GWh/h", '\n',
                                            "DE: ", DE, "\u20ac/MWh"),
                                group = 1)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[4:8])( length(unique(dt.allData$nr)) )) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("AT") +
  ylab("DE")

# Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
scatterPlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Therefore, I get the following plot:

[image]

I would like the data points during the week (Monday to Friday) as **points** represent (as here all) and the data points from Saturday and Sunday (possibly also by national holidays) with an **cross/plus/triangle** represent. How can I do this?

Comment: My suggestion would be to make a variable containing all weekend days / holidays (e.g. `weekends`), then map the shape aesthetic to date membership, i.e. `geom_point(aes(shape = date %in% weekends))`. You can control the exact shapes with the `scale_shape_*()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a factor variable for weekend/weekday in next way, and enable `shape` option in `geom_point()`:

```
#Create day of week
dt.data$Day <- as.numeric(weekdays(dt.data$date) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday'))
dt.data$Day <- factor(dt.data$Day,levels = c(1,0),labels = c('Weekend','Weekday'))
## PLOT: ##
p <- ggplot(data = dt.data, aes(x = AT, y = DE, color = as.factor(nr),
                                text = paste("Date: ", date, '\n',
                                             "AT: ", AT, "GWh/h", '\n',
                                             "DE: ", DE, "\u20ac/MWh"),
                                group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Day)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[4:8])(length(unique(dt.data$nr)))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("AT") +
  ylab("DE")
# Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
scatterPlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

The output will be:

[image]

Or following the sage advice from **@teunbrand**:

```
## PLOT 2
ggplot(data = dt.data, aes(x = AT, y = DE, color = as.factor(nr),
                                text = paste("Date: ", date, '\n',
                                             "AT: ", AT, "GWh/h", '\n',
                                             "DE: ", DE, "\u20ac/MWh"),
                                group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Day)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[4:8])(length(unique(dt.data$nr)))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("AT") +
  ylab("DE") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('Weekend'=1,'Weekday'=3))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have one question to you: Can I force the weekend days to be triangular and days during the week to be displayed as a points? If the first entry in my data table is a weekend, then the weekend days are points, and I don't want that.